# WPF Binding View Model Collection Items to a View without Class Names

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a user control and I can't seem to set it up so I don't have to refer to the class name within the binding.

FullApplicationCollection is an observable class.

This works -- my data shows up:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="TESTREF"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding FullApplicationCollection, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApplication, Mode=TwoWay}" 

                         CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  Height="200">
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel  >
```

This works -- my data shows up:

```
            <TextBox  Text="{Binding SelectedApplication.CustomerMcc,  ValidatesOnExceptions=true, 
        diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10 0 10 10"/>
```

I can't seem to get anything like this to work:

```
            <TextBox Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text=
                 "{Binding CustomerMcc, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
            ValidatesOnExceptions=true, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"   />
```

I would like to refer to Binding PropertyName and not Binding ClassName.PropertyName

I've tried many permutations of setting the context and I just can't seem to get it.

WPF MVVM

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{Binding CustomerMcc}` would work with `DataContext="{Binding SelectedApplication}`, which may also be set on a parent element of the TextBox. It is however unclear why you want do that. Or is the TextBox part of an ItemTemplate, and `CustomerMcc` is an item property?

Comment: You cannot bind directly to a *field*, you must bind to a *property*. I'd also argue the semantics of what you said at the start - `FullApplicationCollection` might well be a *type*, but it is also a *property* name which is why that binding is working.

Comment: Be aware that `SelectedApplication.CustomerMcc` is not something like *ClassName.PropertyName*. Both binding path elements, SelectedApplication and CustomerMcc, are property names.

Comment: @Clemens I have have a large and ever changing model and my design tool won’t include the class name.  Your solution worked by making my non-working example work and my working example not work.  I’ll take it but I wish I understood why!  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens.   That makes more sense.